# How to implement a pictureBox.MoveHover

Tags: c#, mousehover

Event handlers are still a bit new to me. I want to call this method that will change the value of a member in a jagged list from 0 to 1 if the mouse hovers over a certain part of the pictureBox.

```
    public void onMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e, List<List<int>> walls, List<List<int>> positions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < walls.Count; i++)
        {
            int[] mapData = mapController.getMapData(i, walls, positions);
            int column = mapData[0];
            int row = mapData[1];
            int right = mapData[2];
            int bottom = mapData[3];

            if (e.X == column * mapController.map.squareSize)
            {
                mapController.map.cellWalls[i][0] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

The method may be wrong, but i just want to call it first, then i can test it. It's in a class called mapConstructor. I have a form class called mapDesignerView that has the picture box.

To call it i tried this from within the form:

```
private void pbxMap_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    mapConstructor.onMouseUp(e, map.cellPositions, map.cellPositions);
}
```

It won't accept a mouseEvntArgs parameter so says invalid arguments as my method needs the mouseEventArgs. I've tried a few different things too but would like to hear a solution rather than tell you all the wrong things i have tried.

I would like to call it continuously while the mouse is hovering over the picturebox, i think, and when it changes a value of the list, the picturebox will need to redraw itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `X` coordinate of the mouse relative to the `PictureBox`.. since that is the only thing you are using in that method:

```
public void onMouseUp(int xPosition, List<List<int>> walls, List<List<int>> positions)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < walls.Count; i++)
    {
        int[] mapData = mapController.getMapData(i, walls, positions);
        int column = mapData[0];
        int row = mapData[1];
        int right = mapData[2];
        int bottom = mapData[3];

        if (xPosition == column * mapController.map.squareSize)
        {
            mapController.map.cellWalls[i][0] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
private void pbxMap_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var xPosition = pbxMap.PointToClient(MousePosition).X;
    mapConstructor.onMouseUp(xPosition, map.cellPositions, map.cellPositions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will do that. Just to check if it is the full solution to my problem, will this be sort of a continuous thing? I guess pbxMap_MouseHover is preset to track my mouse the whole time it is hovering, and is called contiunously so that when i keep moving over different columns they will dynamically be changing the value in the list?

Comment: No. In that case you want `MouseMove`.. depending on how often you want it called.